# Configure test folder for unit testing in Android studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, robolectric

I have added a folder for unit testing in my android studio project. The default folder is andoidTest but I have added a new folder and name in test instead. ([like robolectric sample tests](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-samples))

When I add test Dependency in my build.gradle under module such as

```
testCompile("junit:junit:${junitVersion}")
testCompile ("org.robolectric:robolectric:${robolectricVersion}")
```

They do not get added to external libraries under project, but when I use the default configuration and use `androidTestCompile`, it can added external libraries.

Then I thought that maybe I should setRoot for tests in gradle, so I used following in android tag in build.gradle:

```
sourceSets {
        androidTest.setRoot('src/test')
}
```

But still problem remained. I can run tests using `gradlew`, but imports in classes in test folder do not apply as well as no external library for test purpose is visible.

Anyone have any solution for this issue?

Comment: You should change in build variants tool window test artifact value from "Andrio tests" to "unit tests"

Comment: And I think this question is already duplicate :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Eugen. If you would like You can share your answer so I can accept. And tell me where is has been asked before.

Comment: That is **test** directory.  What about **androidTest** directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was searching and didn't find answer that I thought already covered this. So decided to create new one for the future.

**Answer**
Android Studio is not picking up unit tests automatically right now. I know it is planned for 1.3 version.

So you have to change test artifact value from `Android Instrumental Tests` to `Unit Tests` in `Build Variants` tool window:
[image]

Answer (score 7):

Almost fine your Gradle script but try do that:

```
sourceSets {
    androidTest.setRoot('src/test')
    androidTest {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any productFlavors ? in case you need to set testApplicationId

Comment: No, there is no flavor.

Comment: So the thing is.. setting root apparently means nothing. You still need to set the source path, as described in this answer. And this actually solved the issue for me.